# Why did AWS EC2 Ubuntu node get wiped on reboot?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I shelled into a functioning AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance, rebooted, tried to shell back into it, and found that I was presented with a different host certificate. I was able to log in based on the same keypair as before, but the node seemed to be initialized to the default state: only dotfiles in ubuntu's home directory, no /etc/apache2, etc.

What happened, and is there any way to revert to what there was before?

Comment: Did you fail to create it with an EBS root?

Comment: @MichaelHampton If it's truly a reboot, shouldn't matter - instance store instances are supposed to survive them. It's stop+start they get wiped with.

Comment: I definitely did a command line reboot, not a control panel stop+start.